# How to exit a batch script when a command is not found

Tags: windows, terminal, shell, batch

I want the terminal to close itself if adb is not recognized.
ADB is a program this script will utilize to detect device.
Here is a bit of my script

```
echo My name is RomBreaker
echo. 
echo And I'm gonna flash your Nexus 5 back to stock 4.4.2
echo.
echo If ADB and Fastboot is not set properly, this of course is pointless
echo.
pause
echo.
echo Rebooting device into Bootloader via ADB
echo.
adb reboot-bootloader
echo.
echo If the above says "device not found" its because your in Fastboot
echo.
echo.........................................................................
echo.
echo If the above says "adb is not recognized" you didn't listen
echo.
```

I want the terminal to close right here. The objective is to write an IF or Else IF that'll close if the program "adb" is not found on PC. Of course if it is, it'll continue.

When adb is not recognized, we get this.

```
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: This is on Windows, right?

Comment: Your title is misleading... You need "IF" statements in your script to check IF a condition is true.

Comment: I've made it a bit more clear. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if %errorlevel% after the execution is 9009, so

```
if %errorlevel% == 9009 exit
```

or instead of exit do what you need to.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to fede.evol's answer, you could use the following command:

```
adb [any args you want to run] || exit
```